# About order of growth

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following problem:

Show that if $\alpha>1$, then

$$F_{\alpha}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|t|^{\alpha}}e^{2\pi i z t}dt$$ is an entire function of growth order $\alpha/(\alpha-1).$

I've already shown that $F_{\alpha}$ is an entire function.

For the part of growth order, the hint of the problem says:

Show that $$\frac{-|t|^{\alpha}}{2}+2\pi|z||t|\leq c|z|^{\alpha/(\alpha-1)},$$ considering two cases $|t|^{\alpha-1}\leq A|z|$ and $|t|^{\alpha-1}\geq A|z|$ for an appropiate $A$.

My question is about the inequality in the hint. I don't know how to prove it (maybe is easy but I don't see it).

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: If $|t|^{a-1} \le A |z|$ then $\frac{-|t|^{\alpha}}{2}+2\pi|z||t| \le 2\pi|z||t|\le \frac{2 \pi}{A} |z|^{\frac{1}{a-1}} |z| =  \frac{2 \pi}{A}  |z|^{a/(a-1)}$

Comment: If $|t|^{a-1} \ge A |z|$ then ...